# how to convert progress4GL dataset output parameter to .net type when consuming the progress4Gl web service

Tags: c#, .net, progress-4gl, openedge

So my Colleague has written a simple web service in progress4GL  which expect from me as input parameter - > dataset and returns me a dataset. here is the web service

```
Define TEMP-TABLE TTList NO-UNDO
       FIELD  CtrlName          AS CHAR
       FIELD  WrdNr             AS INT
       FIELD  Descr             AS CHAR
       FIELD  DescrShort        AS CHAR
       FIELD  DescrTooltip      AS CHAR

       FIELD TRecid             AS INT
       .

DEFINE DATASET ds FOR TTList.

DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER pCoCd                         AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER pLanCd                        AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER pUsrCd                        AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER pFilter                       AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER DATASET                       FOR ds.
DEFINE       OUTPUT PARAMETER pErrorTxt                     AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
```

---

And in .net when I consume the web service .net expect to pass **XmlElement** type for the progress4gl input - output dataset parameter

```
 XmlElement docresult = doc.DocumentElement;
             beaHostDB.TranslateList(pCoCd, languageID, " ", " ", ref  docresult, out pErrorTxt);
```

But Yesterday when my colleague uploaded the web service on the server -  and when I made the new web reference to web service - sudddently for this output - input dataset parameter  .net says that it expects **beaHost.ds11TTList ds11** type. (here beaHost is the name of the reference to the webService ).

Can someone help me ehat might be the problem

!!UPDATE

Here is the wsdl from server (I've provided only snippets with the differences)

```
    schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:BeaWeb:BeaWeb">
    <element name="ds">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="TTArticle">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="ArtCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="Descr" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="Photo" nillable="true" prodata:dataType="prodata:blob" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
    <element name="Price" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
    <element name="CurrCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="AvStockQty" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
    <element name="TRecid" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
    </sequence>
    </complexType>
    </element>
    </sequence>
    </complexType>
    </element>
    <element name="ds2">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="TTArticleGroup">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="ArticleGroupLinkSeqNr" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
    <element name="ParentArticleGroupLinkSeqNr" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
    <element name="PreParentArticleGroupLinkSeqNr" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
    <element name="SeqNr" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
    <element name="ArtGroupCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="Descr" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="Photo" nillable="true" prodata:dataType="prodata:blob" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
    <element name="AltText" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="PgName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="TRecid" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
    </sequence>
    </complexType>
    </element>
    </sequence>
    </complexType>
    </element>
---
<element name="GetArticle">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="pCoCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pLanCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pUsrCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pFilter" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="GetArticleResponse">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="result" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element ref="S2:ds"/>
<element name="pErrorTxt" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="GetArticleGroup">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="pCoCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pLanCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pUsrCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pFilter" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="GetArticleGroupResponse">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="result" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element ref="S2:ds2"/>
<element name="pErrorTxt" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
```

Here is From Localhost the wsdl file

```
complexType name="dsChanges" prodata:datasetName="ds" prodata:isDsChanges="true" prodata:namespace="urn:beawebprogress:BeaWebProgress">
<sequence>
<any/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="ds">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="TTArticle">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="ArtCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="Descr" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="Photo" nillable="true" prodata:dataType="prodata:blob" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
<element name="Price" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
<element name="CurrCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="AvStockQty" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
<element name="TRecid" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<complexType name="ds2Changes" prodata:datasetName="ds2" prodata:isDsChanges="true" prodata:namespace="urn:beawebprogress:BeaWebProgress">
<sequence>
<any/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="ds2">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="TTArticleGroup">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="ArticleGroupLinkSeqNr" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<element name="ParentArticleGroupLinkSeqNr" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<element name="PreParentArticleGroupLinkSeqNr" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<element name="SeqNr" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<element name="ArtGroupCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="Descr" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="Photo" nillable="true" prodata:dataType="prodata:blob" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
<element name="AltText" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="PgName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="TRecid" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
-------------------
<element name="GetArticle">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="pCoCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pLanCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pUsrCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pFilter" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="GetArticleResponse">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="result" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="ds" type="S2:dsChanges"/>
<element name="pErrorTxt" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="GetArticleGroup">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="pCoCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pLanCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pUsrCd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pFilter" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="GetArticleGroupResponse">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="result" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="ds2" type="S2:ds2Changes"/>
<element name="pErrorTxt" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
```

Comment: Is there a WSDL for the web service, can we see it?

Comment: Hi I've publsihed a snippet from the wsdl with the differences

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have it, download SoapUI from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/

In SoapUI, setup a project to call your webservice and see what it returns - my guess is that the name being given to the prodataset and/or the temp-table that's being sent to the client doesn't match what your .Net client is expecting, and that's where the error's coming from.

If this is the case, use the SERIALIZE-NAME attribute to get the names to align between the webservice and the client.

My guess is it's the TT name that doesn't match, so you'd do this:

```
TEMP-TABLE ttlist:SERIALIZE-NAME = "ds11TTList".
```

If it's the dataset, then do this:

```
DATASET ds:SERIALIZE-NAME = "CorrectDsName".
```

Comment: Hi thank you - can you have a quick look from the wsdl thaty return the server and the localhost

Comment: I'm not seeing anything which references beaHost.ds11TTList ds11 in these WSDL's, so I can't help here. You need to find where those names are in your code before you can figure out why there's a mismatch between the webservice and the .Net consumer.